# How can I get the list of database names through webconfig in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a combo box in login screen.In that combo box I need the names of database.How can I do this? please help

Comment: Where are keeping your database configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the list of connection strings defined in .config file by using [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
// Get the ConnectionStrings section.         
// This function uses the ConnectionStrings  
// property to read the connectionStrings 
// configuration section. 
public static void ReadConnectionStrings()
{

  // Get the ConnectionStrings collection.
  ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connections =
      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

  if (connections.Count != 0)
  {
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Using ConnectionStrings property.");
    Console.WriteLine("Connection strings:");

    // Get the collection elements. 
    foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connection in 
      connections)
    {
      string name = connection.Name;
      string provider = connection.ProviderName;
      string connectionString = connection.ConnectionString;

      Console.WriteLine("Name:               {0}", 
        name);
      Console.WriteLine("Connection string:  {0}", 
        connectionString);
     Console.WriteLine("Provider:            {0}", 
        provider);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("No connection string is defined.");
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

Remember to add a reference to `System.Configuration` assembly.